# Add find inside pipe

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following code :

```
await this.panelService.getActivePanels().subscribe(activePanels => {
      panel = activePanels.find(panel => panel.serviceId === serviceId);
    });
```

I want to add a pipe before the subscribe, that does the find operation,  so when I subscribe I will get just the one panel returned by the find, is that possible? and how would it look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [`map`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) and you can use it like this:

```
this.panelService.getActivePanels().pipe(
  map(activePanels => activePanels.find(panel => panel.serviceId === serviceId))
).subscribe(panel => {
  console.log(panel);
});
```